# How to change the default .ivy2 cache directory to something else?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka

My username has space in it and when running spark structured streaming with kafka it is unable to find the path to .ivy2 folder and the corresponding .jar file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `defaultCacheDir` to change the default location as documented [here](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/caches.html)

You need to make an entry in `ivysettings.xml` with something like below

```
<ivysettings>
    <caches defaultCacheDir="/path/to/my/cache/dir"/>
</ivysettings>
```